# Why is this SQL case statement behaving like an OR statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Consider the following query:

```
declare @RentalId int = 1

SELECT 
     r.RentalId
    ,r.[Name]
    ,rt.TypeId


FROM dbo.Rental r
LEFT JOIN dbo.RentalRateType rt ON (
    r.RentalId = rt.RentalId
    AND rt.TypeId = (
        case when rt.TypeId = 6 and coalesce(rt.[Max], rt.[Min]) is not null then 6
         when rt.TypeId = 1 and coalesce(rt.[Max], rt.[Min] is not null then 1 
        else -1 end
))
WHERE r.RentalId = @RentalId
```

I'm attempting to return a single record/row. The particular rental in question has 2 records in the `dbo.RentalRateType` table, and when I run the above query, I get 2 results, but I want it to short circuit on the first match in the `case where`.

Basically, the end user can fill in multiple rate types, more than what you see in this example, and each of those types has a priority. 6 is the highest priority in the example.

So I'm getting this result:

```
RentalId |   Name   | TypeId
----------------------------
1          Super Car  6    
1          Super Car  1
```

But if the type (6) exists, I would expect only the first row above returned.

I must be missing something silly. This works as expected:

```
case when 1=2 then 6
     when 1=1 then 1 
     else -1 end
```

While I'm here, I'm open to a more efficient manner of handling this if exists.

Comment: I'm not sure on your specific requirements but the reason you're getting two results is because both fulfill the case expression's conditions... Maybe you're just looking for a `TOP 1` with an order by based on whatever you're looking for?

Comment: Why have you written an `inner join` as a `left outer join` with a reference to the right-hand table in the `where` clause (`... and rt.TypeId = ...`) that doesn't allow nulls?

Comment: @HABO I need to account for situations where no rate has been entered and still return a record (reason for left join) -edit- yes I see what you mean with the WHERE clause. That's because I was moving it around to test (Was within the ON (... ).

Comment: @HABO I'll fix my example

Comment: @ZLK Right. My goal is to return a single row. If the user has a rate type of 6, use that one, otherwise use 1. Now in my real application there are more like 5 different rate types, each having a priority.

Comment: Can you put some sample data in, the expected results and the actual results you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `apply` instead, these are an efficient way to get "top n" queries:

```
SELECT
    r.RentalId
  , r.[Name]
  , oa.TypeId
FROM dbo.Rental r
OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT TOP (1)
            rt.TypeId
        FROM dbo.RentalRateType rt
        WHERE r.RentalId = rt.RentalId
        ORDER BY
            rt.TypeId DESC
    ) oa
WHERE r.RentalId = @RentalId
```